# Conditional formatting formulas in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I want to use Conditional formatting so all of the cells in column `A` change colors whenever the matching cells in column `B` have the word *"later"*.
ex: If cell `B20` contains *"later"*, then I want `A20` to change colors. (font or fill, anything)

I've tried everything, nothing seems to be working.

My range is `A10:A998`

And my custom formula is: `=$B10:B998="later"`

I've also tried it without the `$` sign in the beginning.
Is this rule not working because I have another rule for column `A`? The other rule changes the text color if it contains a check mark, but that is only within its own column.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

**custom formula applicable to range A10:A998:** **`=B10="later"`**

[image: 0]